# ansible: stdout to list and dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

below is output of the "RESULT":

```
stdout:
- |-
  ospf T1 VRF vrf1
  ospf T2 VRF vrf2
  ospf T3 VRF vrf3
stdout_lines:
  - ospf T1 VRF vrf1
  - ospf T2 VRF vrf2
  - ospf T3 VRF vrf3
```

I want output in list and in dictionary:

1st output will be list. list will have following:

```
 - T1
 - T2
 - T3
```

2nd output will be list like below:

```
ospf_vrf:
  - vrf: vrf1
    process: T1
  - vrf: vrf2
    process: T2
  - vrf: vrf3
    process: T3
```

3rd output will be dictionary.

how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by parsing the data from `stdout` via regex. Assuming the components in your output are always: `ospf <process_value> VRF <vrf_falue>`, the regex looks like this:

```
{{ stdout | regex_findall('^ospf (.+) VRF (.+)$', multiline=True) }}
```

Based on this, you can then put the values into different forms and store them in variables:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    ospf: "{{ extracted | map('first') }}"
    ospf_vrf: "{{ extracted | map('zip', ['process', 'vrf']) |
      map('map', 'reverse') | map('community.general.dict') }}"
    ospf_dict: "{{ dict(extracted) }}"
    vrf_dict: "{{ dict(extracted | map('reverse')) }}"
  vars:
    extracted: "{{ stdout | regex_findall('^ospf (.+) VRF (.+)$', multiline=True) }}"
```

- `extracted` is a helper with the regex values and the base for all other values
- `ospf` is a list of the process_values
  In each case the first element of the regex is taken.
- `ospf_vrf` is a list of dicts

  1. the keys process and vrf are assigned to the regex values
  2. by `reverse` the keys are brought to the front
  3. by `community.general.dict` a dict is created from the key-value pairs
- `ospf_dict`: a dict based on process
- `vrf_dict`: a dict based on vrf

*Note: Both `ospf_dict` and `vrf_dict` will lose values if there are duplicates for the keys.*

The output of the 4 variables looks like this:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ospf": [
        "T1",
        "T2",
        "T3"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ospf_vrf": [
        {
            "process": "T1",
            "vrf": "vrf1"
        },
        {
            "process": "T2",
            "vrf": "vrf2"
        },
        {
            "process": "T3",
            "vrf": "vrf3"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ospf_dict": {
        "T1": "vrf1",
        "T2": "vrf2",
        "T3": "vrf3"
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vrf_dict": {
        "vrf1": "T1",
        "vrf2": "T2",
        "vrf3": "T3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this sample playbook for your requirements. I am not clear on third expected output. please clarify on that

---

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    stdout_lines:
      - ospf T1 VRF vrf1
      - ospf T2 VRF vrf2
      - ospf T3 VRF vrf3

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        first_output: "{{ first_output | default([]) +  [ (item | split())[1] ] }}"

      with_items: 
        "{{ stdout_lines }}"

    - debug:
        var: first_output

    - set_fact:
          second_output: "{{ second_output | default([]) +  [ { 'vrf': (item | split())[3] , 'process': (item | split())[1] } ] }}"

      with_items: 
        "{{ stdout_lines }}"

    - debug:
        var: second_output
```